# why tcsh script choke on special characters inside file eg. #{ on a line is giving missing "}" error

Tags: shell-script, shell, tcsh, csh

I'm using tcsh shell script to read each line of a file input.txt

## script

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set out_file_length=`wc -l<$1`
set i=1
while ( $i <= $out_file_length )
    set each_line = `head -$i input.txt | tail -1`
    echo $each_line
    @ i++
end
```

sample input:
input file can have either #{ or #} in lines which is choking my script

## input.txt

```
welcome
to
#{
tcsh
#}
programming
```

## this is the output i got

```
welcome
to
Missing }.
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: you might try `"$( head -$i input.txt | tail -1 )"` and `echo "${each_line}"`. I suspect having an unquoted # at the start of a substitution is messing the syntax. But I don't know tcsh, or have it installed to test, and shellcheck won't work on it, so what do I know? It just looks odd to me.

Comment: It is badly quoted. I don't know `tcsh` (not used in years). In bash you can use `"$(head -"$i" input.txt | tail -1)"` The inner quotes are not needed, but I included as it is best to always have them (even if not needed).

Comment: tcsh doesn't support `$(...)`, so I'd try `"\`head -$i input.txt | tail -1\`"` and either `echo "$each_line"` or `echo $each_line:q`

Comment: You got it backwards. If somebody suggests a solution and it doesn’t work for you, you should say so in a comment or an edit to the question.  But when you get the problem solved, if it hasn’t already been posted as an answer, then you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mark Plotnick for your repy:

```
"`head -$i input.txt | tail -1`"
echo $each_line:q
```

this worked and didn't show the missing } error.
i was able to move it to a variable and used it for string comparison also.